# Moving from Solr to SolrCloud

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, xconnect

We are currently working on a Sitecore project where we are using

1. **Sitecore XP 9.0.2** and
2. **Sitecore XC 9.0.3** with
3. Standalone **Solr 6.6.2**

As we are growing in terms of user base, we are looking to move from standalone Solr as a single point of failure to SolrCloud. We have successfully configured SolrCloud and re-indexed Sitecore XP indexes with Switch-On-Rebuild enabled. But this was done on Staging region and now we are planning to move the same to Production region.

Currently we have close to **50** GB of data on various Solr cores, the largest one of them being xDB with 40 GB data. The strategy we have thought of for a zero downtime migration is cloning our CM server in production and changing the Solr url in the cloned server from standalone Solr to the SolrCloud load balancer and reindex all the collections. Our concern here is that the xDB index has close to 40GB data, will reindexing this amount of data using the cloned CM server work? If it won't then is there any other way to reindex large sized xDB on SolrCloud?

Comment: Are you using xConnect at all? As in using IdentifyAs or any custom facets.

Comment: Hi @chris-auer, right now we aren't using it too much, but yes we would like to do certain analytics work on the data collected by xDB in near future. If we don't migrate the existing xDB data then we will loose the information collected in last several months.

Comment: Then you can just rebuild the xDB solr indexes when you get the indexes created in the Solr Cloud. Since you don't use the data you wont have any downtime issues.